# Ionic Find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

//users.html

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
  <h2>{{ user.id }}</h2>
  <h2>{{ user.name }}</h2>
  <h2>{{ user.number }}</h2>
  <ion-icon name="arrow-forward" item-right></ion-icon>
</button>
```

//users.ts

```
 Component({
 selector: 'page-users',
 templateUrl: 'users.html',
 })
 export class UsersPage {

    users: User[]

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
 public navParams: NavParams, public githubUsersProvider: 
 GithubUsersProvider) {
 githubUsersProvider.load().subscribe(users => {

  this.users = users;
})
}

 ionViewDidLoad() {
  console.log('ionViewDidLoad UsersPage');
 }}
```

//user.ts (model)

```
export interface User {

  id: number;
  number: number;
  name: string;

  }
```

//github-users.ts

```
 @Injectable()
 export class GithubUsersProvider {
 githubApiUrl = 'URL';

 constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
 console.log('Hello GithubUsersProvider Provider');
 }
```

// Load all github users

```
 load(): Observable<User[]> {
   return this.http.get(`${this.githubApiUrl}`)
     //.map(res:Response) => res.json().data);
       .map(res => <User[]>res);
    }
   }
```

// my response URL

```
   {"status": "OK","results": [{"id":"136","number":"255","name":"hello 
      ionic"},
     {"id":"137","number":"256","name":"goodbye"
   }]}
```

I just learned Ionic and don't know what's wrong with my code.

There is an error:

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of
>   type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

.

Comment: try `.map(res => <User[]>res.results)` instead of `.map(res => <User[]>res)` and `this.http.get(\`${this.githubApiUrl}\`, { observe: 'response' })` instead of `this.http.get(\`${this.githubApiUrl}\`)`

Comment: Blank page cannot show any data.

Comment: // Load all github users
  load(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.githubApiUrl}`, { observe: 'response' })
      //.map(res:Response) => res.json().data);
      .map(res => <User[]>res.results);
  }
}